# Detect format of string and parse

Tags: c++, string, format, scanf

I have a string in the following format :

```
dateTime =  "2016-03-22T11:10:41.3126731+00:00"
```

Which I parse into a **tm** struct as follows:

```
    struct tm utc;
    int microseconds;

    sscanf_s(dateTime.c_str(), "%04d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02d.%d", 
                                &utc.tm_year,
                                &utc.tm_mon, 
                                &utc.tm_mday,
                                &utc.tm_hour,
                                &utc.tm_min,
                                &utc.tm_sec,
                                &microseconds);
```

But now I need to parse another string in this format:

```
dateTime = "3/18/2016 12:00:05 AM -05:00"
```

I do not know in advance the format of the string.

What is the best way to **detect** the format and **parse** accordingly??

Comment: Something like [this](http://devdocs.io/cpp/regex/regex_match)?

Comment: That is actually not so easy. Take the date 10/9/2016, is it the tenth of September, or the ninth of October? Most of the world would say it was the tenth of September, though over 300 million north-Americans would disagree. So the parsing of the data depends on where it comes from, it can't be fixed. If you get that as part of some protocol then I would say that the protocol is either flawed that allows multiple formats, or flawed if it doesn't specify the exact formats allowable and their interpretations. Have you actually read any specification about the data you receive?

Comment: In both cases the month is first followed by the day.

Answer (score 0):

If Boost is available in your project try [Date Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/date_time.html) library, but you could meet cases that are not supported. If the standard library is a must, then try [regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/regex) to extract parameters and put them into `struct tm`. But that's for the case that you know the format in advance. To detect the format and then to parse would require more advanced logic than offered by these two libraries, and it's far from being trivial.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have those two formats, and you know if the day or the month comes first, then it's very easy to detect which format you need to use for the `sscanf` call. Simply check the third character. Is it a slash (`'/'`) or a digit?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the format in advance, you *might* be able to determine the format by a process of elimination. For "3/18/2016", you *have* to have "month/day/year", because 2016 is too large to be anything other than a year, and 18 is too large to signify a month.

If, however, you're faced with something like "3/8/10", you simply don't have any basis for guessing which field is supposed to signify what.